# Refreshing nested Iframe in the Selenium script

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on an application which has nested Iframes in the UI. Some of the Iframes refresh during test execution. Is there any way we can simulate refreshing Iframe using Selenium?  I have tried using Javascript and WebDriverWait but it didn't work.

I have used following methods:

```
public static void waitForIframeToLoad(String frameName){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameName));
}


public static void refreshIFrameUsingJavaScript(String iFrameName)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript(String.format("document.getElementById('{0}').src = " + 
  "document.getElementById('{0}').src", iFrameName));
 }
```

However both these methods are not working. I am able to switch between frames using driver.switchTo().frame("main").switchTo().frame("framename")

The frame 'main' is the parent frame and it holds multiple child frames. The child frames refresh after user clicks on some button and I need to verify some text in the child frame after it refreshes. 
However after the child frame refreshes, I am unable to access any elements in the script. Has anyone worked on the similar scenario? what is the best possible workaround for this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("Why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

When you refreshed, your webelement objects become "stale" and are no longer the same objects. You need to (re) instantiate your webelement object(s). You may need to even switch back to the Parent frame first, then go to the child frame, and finally instantiate your webelement objects.